# What does fn in jQuery stand for?

Tags: jquery

I know jQuery.fn is just an alias of jQuery.prototype, but what does "fn" stand for? Does it have a full name?

For example, "formal name"? "formal namespace"? I've no idea.

Comment: It is shorthand for function.

Comment: I'll add that in Basic, to define a function you wrote `DEF FN` :-)

Comment: @xan Obvious connection, since jQuery compiles down to BASIC... ;o)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fn` as in **f** unctio **n**.

It is also the name of the formal parameter wherever a function is expected:

```
// Bind a function to a context, optionally partially applying any
// arguments.
proxy: function( fn, context ) {
```

Comment: They named it `fn` _whoopee_, but you can easily rename it. it does not **have to** be  called `fn`

Comment: @Neal ? The op asked what does "fn" stand for, and it stands for the word "function"

Comment: Also why couldn't it be `fn` as in **f** u **n** ction? :-P

Comment: @Neal I don't know, I just made it up

Comment: Thanks Esailija for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.fn` is just an alias for jQuery.prototype (which just saves us time when coding such `jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn = $.fn` as such).

If you remember about `prototypes` functions in JavaScript Objects, then it would make total sense.

Remember, `JQuery` itself is an object.
This [article](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/#.UAa2zaPNkao) can help you to better understand.

Comment: Thanks philippe, probably it's a shorthand for "function", but is there any official document for this information? Or, is it conventional?