# Why does jQuery alias its prototype to `fn`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Just look at any jQuery plugin's source code. It's always

```
$.fn.pluginName = function() {
    foo('bar');
    return baz;
};
```

Where does the `fn` name come from, and is it just a simple alias to `$.prototype`, or does it serve some other purpose(s), as well?

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527031/jquery-fn-namespace and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542017/what-does-fn-in-jquery-stand-for

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755080/why-jquery-do-this-jquery-fn-init-prototype-jquery-fn

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jquery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L84):

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
```

It's just an alias, a shortcut, just like how `jQuery` and `$` are the same.

Comment: Fine, but where do they get the string "fn" from? That evokes the word "function" in my mind, which makes no sense.  Wouldn't `jQuery.pt` make more sense?

Comment: @adlwalrus I have no idea. It may be an inside-story or something of the sorts. I'll try digging in the older sources. Edit: Maybe it's to denote that there should only be functions there?

Comment: @adlwalrus Asked on irc, they seem to think as I, so I [tweeted](https://twitter.com/zirakertan/status/263576846350823424) John Resig. Hopefully we'll have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

fn is the part of the jquery library controls element selection so `$.foo = function () {};` will not exist for `$('#a').foo();` but `$.fn.foo = function () {};` will. Similarly, `$.fn.foo` will not exist if you try `$.foo();`. It also makes the this keyword relevant to the current element used. And your comment about "any jquery plugin having fn" isn't true ;)